# Vlookup error message when comparing 2 opened workbooks

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I have a problem with my code below:

Code:

```
Sub CPT_Click()


    Dim CPTBook, PRBook As Workbook
    Dim CPTSheet, PRSheet As Worksheet
    Dim CPTRange As Range
    Dim myResult, lookValue As String


    Set PRBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set PRSheet = PRBook.Worksheets("Implementation")
    Set CPTBook = Workbooks.Open("CPT.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
    Set CPTSheet = CPTBook.Worksheets(2)
    Set CPTRange = CPTSheet.Range("G4:DY300")

    lookValue = PRSheet.Range("U18").Value   'returns correct value
    myResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookValue, CPTRange, 2, False)
    MsgBox myResult


End Sub
```

When I click on my button, I get the famous: "Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class" error message.

I have tried everything and when typing the Vlookup function inside the sheet, I get the correct value - so the value I'm looking for (lookValue) in CPTSheet within the CPTRange.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the CPTRange's External attribute of the Address property to true.  I would also use the Evaluate method for this:

```
myResult = Evaluate("VLookup(""" & lookValue & """," & CPTRange.Address(External:=True) & ",2,False)")
```